# Python 3 error handling running both try and except

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to implement error handling in a Python 3 script by getting the SMTPlib library to send an email when it encounters an error like this..

```
if value.isdigit() :
    print ("Value is an integer")
else :
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(email_server, email_port)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email_login, email_pass)
        server.sendmail("me@example.com", "me@example.com", message)
        server.close()
        sys.exit()
    except:
        print ("Error - Was unable to send email")
        sys.exit()
```

This works correctly if the value is an integer, but if it is not then the email gets correctly sent but the Error message is also printed to the screen.

Why is my script running the except section as well?

Comment: Add a call to `traceback.print_exc()` in your exception handling code to find out what exception was raised (which is why the except section is being executed).

Comment: guessing from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.quit) you might've meant `server.quit()` rather than `server.close()`?

Comment: You are probably catching the `SystemExit` exception from `sys.exit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sys.exit` is implemented by raising an exception. When `sys.exit` is called after `server.close`, that `SystemExit` exception is caught.

Here is a little proof:

```
import sys 

try:
  print("hello")
  sys.exit()
except:
  print("exception!")
```

The basic rules for exception handling were not obeyed. At least `except Exception:` should have been used. Better `except Exception as err:` with `err` logged or printed. And the best approach is to handle only exceptions originating from the SMTP transaction guarded by `try/except`.

Comment: Do I even need to sys.exit?  Does the fact that it has reached an except means the program will terminate anyway?

Comment: @fightstarr20 you're doing a `sys.exit()` regardless of whether there's an exception - why not bring it outside of the `try...except...` loop?

Comment: @fightstarr20 `sys.exit()` is best used with error code, 0 for success, non-zero for a failure. This is useful for usage in scripts.